# Create android sdk for developers .. how to hide the sdk classes visibility from the developers !.. like facebook - uber sdk

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, android-library

Iam working on creating sdk for developer like uber .. 
My Questions is:

how to control the classes visibility .. I need the developers that use this sdk to just only see the Entry Point Class .. not to see all the sdk classes with keep the structure of the project clean .. no put all classes in one package and make them protected or default access modifier.

Comment: Well, i think it's an IDE rules, once your app run your code became available.
Also **Reading code harder than write it**.
I just  advice you to forget that and go on, just code and you will always have the first mark!

Comment: Also i noticed that the question head very different from it's content.